# framework7 - How to publish to the app store?

Tags: html-framework-7

I am new to Framework7 and would like to know how to publish to the app store. I was not able to find information about this on the Framework7 website. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Cordova / PhoneGap project and replace the placeholder www folder contents with your F7 code. At that point it's just like any other Cordova / PhoneGap app.

https://cordova.apache.org/ or http://phonegap.com/ or countless answers here on StackOverflow.

Comment: just to add, you need access to mac computer to publish apps to app store

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intel XDK, it's a free tool, and with framework7 it's a good combination.
There are also a lot of commercial platforms. Telerik is a good choice too.

Comment: XDK is obsolete and isn't supported anymore.